# Is it possible to tunnel a display from docker to ec2 instance and then to local?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, x11, display

I'll try to be as clear and complete as possible. I'm working with Ubuntu and from my local laptop I ssh to an ec2 instance (AWS): in doing this I'm using "-X" flag to enable x11 tunneling and as a matter of fact if I do xclock or xmessage when ssh'd, everything get displayed locally in the right way. Now, I setup a docker inside the ec2 instance, which contains some ROS stuff and in particular should open RVIZ: to run the docker the command

```
sudo xhost local:root
```

is used. This is the issue, even if I try to solely run rviz instead of using that command, in both cases I get the error:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
xhost:  unable to open display "localhost:10.0"
```

which instead does not appear when trying xclock and xmessage

Is this something that is not possible to do in any way? I read all related stuff on this website (Magic cookie, xauth and so on) but I can't find a solution, can you help me please?

Comment: If you can get the right chain of forwarding and X cookies together it's theoretically possible.  But that's not really a programming-related question.  [unix.se] might be a better place to ask about the X Window System.